# When creating XML with jQuery should one use $('<xml/>') or $.parseXML('<xml/>')?

Tags: jquery, xml, html

I've found that $('') causes attributes to be re-organized and an xml namespace to be assigned, but $.parseXML() preserves the integrity of the original xml string.  I'm not sure if that is a good thing.

Comment: You should use `$.parseXML`, `$` parses it as HTML

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies the results I'm seeing.  It appears that $.parseXML is creating a new Document while $() is possibly inserting within the page's DOM.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for [`parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

> jQuery.parseXML uses the native parsing function of the browser to create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and manipulated.

So if you are trying to create an XML document you would want to use `parseXML`.

---

Per Esailija, you can then do `$($.parseXML(xml))` and traverse the XML document with jQuery. Do not pass the string directly as xml being interpreted as html will have different rules. For example, in html, param tag must be a self closing tag.

Comment: You can do `$($.parseXML(xml))` and traverse the xml document with jQuery. Do not pass the string directly as xml being interpreted as html will have different rules. For example, in html, `param` tag must be a self closing tag.

Comment: @Esailija - Thanks for clarifying. I just updated my answer to include your comments.

Comment: I'm also able to traverse and modify the new document if I say, $($.parseXML('<xml/>')).  Obviously, this is less concise, but I'm wondering whether one approach is better in some way, especially with performance. Can you clarify why $('<xml/>') is re-ordering the attributes and adding a namespace?  Is there additional processing using $('')?

Comment: Well, according to Esailija and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 - the `$('')` function expects an HTML string and not XML. This probably explains some of the modifications.

Comment: @MichaelPrescott: when you parse a string, you are converting it to a different structure. Therefore only information in the original string that is considered significant will be preserved. Order of attributes is not considered significant in XML (or HTML).